# For loop in a package function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, package

I have this for loop, meant to search through a list of URLs and calls a function to scrape off the web and return a list of recipes where a match occurs. It works great on its own.

```
for (recipe_url in recipe_urls) {
  if ("allrecipes.*" %rin% recipe_urls){
    scrape_allrecipes(recipe_url)
  }
  if("foodnetwork.*" %rin% recipe_urls){
    scrape_foodnetwork(recipe_url)
  }
}
```

Note: `%rin%` is a custom function to search for a partial string of text.

```
`%rin%` = function (pattern, list) {
  vapply(pattern, function (p) any(grepl(p, list)), logical(1L), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
```

However, the problem is that when I tried to put it inside of a function in a package, it gives me this error:

```
Error in for (recipe_url in recipe_urls) { : invalid for() loop sequence
```

Version I converted to a function in a package:

```
scrape <- function(scrape) {
for (recipe_url in recipe_urls) {
  if ("allrecipes.*" %rin% recipe_urls){
    scrape_allrecipes(recipe_url)
  }
  if("foodnetwork.*" %rin% recipe_urls){
    scrape_foodnetwork(recipe_url)
  }
}
}
```

I sense that it's either to do with it now being in a function, or something to do with how a package works (never made a package before so I am unfamiliar).

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: That seemed to fix it! What does the () after function do anyways? I have typically used it to name the function in RStudio... and I have been calling it whatever I like without issue. Edit: The user seemed to delete their comment, thank you nonetheless! The solution was to use function(recipe_urls)

Comment: Your example was not reproducible, so I thought it wouldn't work.  You may also need to collect and return the output from the loop

Comment: All the functions are working perfectly now. Thanks for your help.